# how do i define a method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have generated scaffold for a author and I want to add an email address to the table.
I have added author.email in my tags and it wants me to define a method. what method should i define for email and where? is it in the authors controller.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `email` is a field for the `author`. You should add it to your database migration, rerun the `rake db:migrare` and it'll be accessible as `author.email`

Also, make sure to add `:email` to the `attr_accessible` list in your `author` model.

Comment: it says undefined method 'email' for Author, i have do db:migrate a couple of time and db:seed

Comment: `db:migrate` will run new migrations. Did you add a new migration or edit the old one?

Comment: Please read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html It describes how to create new migrations and rerun existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it incorrectly. As i believe you receiving error call " undefined method or variable call email" isn't it??
If so that means you need to add email field to the database table table you can do that by following commands

```
ruby script/generate migration AddEmailToAuthor email:string
rake db:migrate
```

now you can run your program